# Roles in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

If in Marketing cloud are 2 roles :
Administrator and Marketing Cloud Administrator,
if I remove Administrator what does it amble to my user?
What does administrator do ?

Answer (score 1):

The confusion around those two separate Administrator roles originates from the early days, where Email Studio had its own roles. Hence the Administrator manages all the Email Studio admin tasks, while Marketing Cloud Administrator manages all the rest. Hence if you remove Administrator, you will still be able to e.g. access all of the features, except Email Studio, as per the table below:

[image]

[Source](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_roles.htm&type=5)